# Vim - writing to filename in vimscript variable

Tags: vim

I'm doing something like

```
:let foo="bar"
:echom foo
bar
:w foo
"foo" [New File] 0 lines, 0 characters written
```

I am expecting/hoping to write a file named "bar", not a file named "foo". Assuming that I have a string stored in a variable "foo", how can I write the current buffer to a file with the name being that string?

As an aside, can someone explain what `:w foo` and `:echom foo` are doing different with regards to `foo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Vimscript evaluation rules

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```

Like `:execute` above, the `:echo[msg` command is particular in that it takes a *variable* argument, whereas most commands (like `:write`) do not, and treat the argument(s) literally.

#### Your particular problem

As above, your issue is best resolved via `execute`:

```
:execute 'write' foo
```

However, note that if `foo` contains any regular filename, it still needs to be *escaped* for the `:write` function, which understands some special notation (e.g. `%` stands for the current buffer name), and likes to have spaces escaped:

```
:execute 'write' fnameescape(foo)
```

Answer (score 4):

Only

```
:execute 'write ' . foo<CR>
```

and

```
:write <C-r>=foo<CR><CR>
```

do what you want.

Variables can be used in a concatenation, case 1, or in an expression, case 2.